# How to know in the application that neo4j recovered from a crash during the last startup

Tags: java, neo4j, crash

Sometimes after a power failure, when I start neo4j server, I see that its trying to recover from a crash. Is there some way to know in the application that such a recovery happened? I'm using neo4j embedded in my java application. Also, I'm using neo4j community 2.0.1 via blueprints.

Comment: You can read `messages.log` from graph.db path.